# Splitting a string based on a set length of characters

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, itext

MVC 3. Vb.net. Part of my app generates PDF files using Itextsharp. Some strings are too long to go onto the background image correctly. So I basically need to split this string when its over 26 characters long and when it splits it cant split in the middle of a word. from there I will use newline to add the string to the right to the next line... Any ideas that might point me in the right direction..   I did start bulding the function that I will pass the string into test for length and then pass back the string after it finishes but I am stummped after that..

```
    Private Function stringLength(ByVal _string As String) As String
        If _string.Length < 26 Then
            _string.Split(
        End If
    End Function
```

Comment: Here is a similar question with a c# answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815021/split-large-text-string-into-variable-length-strings-without-breaking-words-and

Its worth noting though that most fonts are variable width so the character count may not actually correspond to a pixel width

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I am out of gas on this part of the app... I will just shrink the font's till they fit.. I know nothing about c and when its converted its full of errors that I don't really understand.. Thanks again..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there's a million different ways to do this.

You basically need to get all of your words split by the space into a list.  After that, you just need to keep checking if the current word plus a space plus the next word reach your threshold or not, and if it does, you move to the next line.  Once you have all of your lines, then you rejoin the list into a single string again.

```
Private Function LimitWidth(ByVal text As String, ByVal maxCharacters As Integer) As String
  Dim words As List(Of String) = text.Split(" "c).ToList()

  If text.Length < maxCharacters OrElse words.Count = 1 Then
    Return text
  Else
    Dim lines As New List(Of String)

    Dim currentLine As String = words(0)
    For i As Integer = 1 To words.Count - 1
      If (currentLine & " " & words(i)).Length > maxCharacters Then
        lines.Add(currentLine)
        currentLine = words(i)

        If i = words.Count - 1 Then
          lines.Add(currentLine)
        End If
      Else
        If i = words.Count - 1 Then
          lines.Add(currentLine & " " & words(i))
        End If

        currentLine &= " " & words(i)
      End If
    Next

    Return String.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines.ToArray())
  End If
End Function
```

To Test:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  MessageBox.Show(LimitWidth("This is a really long sentence " & _
                             "meant to demonstrate how to split " & _
                             "the words into a confined character length.", 26))
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply... I emplemented it and used breaks to watch what was going on... Problem is though I am using contentbyte in itextsharp.. from the flow of the function and the Newline on the return I believe that this splits up the string where it needs to be and inserts the Newline in the specific spots then returns this as one string.. Problem is that this is that contentbyte just treats it as one line. I am using contentbyte to control page positioning of items. It is defindately in the right area though. May attempt to get it to return a list of string so I can pull each line there.

Comment: Ok so this is the path I am on with it... I removed the environment.newline and put a delimiter there... That way it returns the string with a delimiter present.. Then I can split accordingly from there and assign the left side to the first line and the right to the right side.. I have code laying around here that you gave me to handle delimiters I can tweak it up a bit.. Thanks alot man..

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are asking for a word wrap function.

Since I feel that it's better to answer in a way that promotes learning than to just give answers, I have for you a link that walks you through the process of using Test Driven Development (TDD) to solve this problem. It just so happens that the word wrap problem is a popular coding kata, and Robert C. Martin wrote a somewhat silly fictional story about a developer being taught how to use TDD to solve the word wrap kata.

The code examples are in Java, but it should be trivial to read and translate.

http://thecleancoder.blogspot.com/2010/10/craftsman-62-dark-path.html

The goofy bits are skip-able. Just jump down to the sentences right before the first code snippet.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I went through it and made an attempt at it. I am just learning my way through vb.net so converting something from java to vb.net is a little above my curve right now.. I will just shrink the fonts on the pdf and if my customer dont like it I will deal with it when the time comes.

Answer (score 0):

I would add to it handling of multiline input text with following:

```
Private Function LimitWidth(ByVal text As String, ByVal maxCharacters As Integer, SplitSign As String) As String
    Dim Output As String = ""
    Dim OrgLines As List(Of String) = text.Split(Environment.NewLine).ToList()
    For x As Integer = 1 To OrgLines.Count - 1
        Dim words As List(Of String) = OrgLines(x).Split(" "c).ToList()
        If text.Length < maxCharacters OrElse words.Count = 1 Then
            Output += OrgLines(x)
        Else
            Dim lines As New List(Of String)

            Dim currentLine As String = words(0)
            For i As Integer = 1 To words.Count - 1
                If (currentLine & " " & words(i)).Length > maxCharacters Then
                    lines.Add(currentLine)
                    currentLine = words(i)

                    If i = words.Count - 1 Then
                        lines.Add(currentLine)
                    End If
                Else
                    If i = words.Count - 1 Then
                        lines.Add(currentLine & " " & words(i))
                    End If

                    currentLine &= " " & words(i)
                End If
            Next
            Output += String.Join(SplitSign, lines.ToArray())
        End If
    Next
    Return Output
End Function
```

use:

LimitWidth("your text", 80, Environment.NewLine)