# Splitting string into different line lengths

Tags: python, string, split

I'm trying to split a variable length string across different but predefined line lengths. I've thrown together some code below which fails on key error 6 when I plonk it into [Python Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com) (I don't have access to a proper python IDE right now) I guess this means my while loop isn't working properly and it's trying to keep incrementing lineNum but I'm not too sure why. Is there a better way to do this? Or is this easily fixable?

The code:

```
import re

#Dictionary containing the line number as key and the max line length
lineLengths = {
        1:9,
        2:11,
        3:12,
        4:14,
        5:14
               }

inputStr = "THIS IS A LONG DESC 7X7 NEEDS SPLITTING"        #Test string, should be split on the spaces and around the "X"

splitted = re.split("(?:\s|((?<=\d)X(?=\d)))",inputStr)     #splits inputStr on white space and where X is surrounded by numbers eg. dimensions

lineNum = 1                         #initialises the line number at 1

lineStr1 = ""                           #initialises each line as a string
lineStr2 = ""
lineStr3 = ""
lineStr4 = ""
lineStr5 = ""

#Dictionary creating dynamic line variables
lineNumDict = {
        1:lineStr1,
        2:lineStr2,
        3:lineStr3,
        4:lineStr4,
        5:lineStr5
        }

if len(inputStr) > 40:
    print "The short description is longer than 40 characters"
else:
    while lineNum <= 5:
        for word in splitted:
            if word != None:
                if len(lineNumDict[lineNum]+word) <= lineLengths[lineNum]:
                    lineNumDict[lineNum] += word
                else:
                    lineNum += 1
            else:
                if len(lineNumDict[lineNum])+1 <= lineLengths[lineNum]:
                    lineNumDict[lineNum] += " "
                else:
                    lineNum += 1

lineOut1 = lineStr1.strip()
lineOut2 = lineStr2.strip()
lineOut3 = lineStr3.strip()
lineOut4 = lineStr4.strip()
lineOut5 = lineStr5.strip()
```

I've taken a look at this answer but don't have any real understanding of C#: [Split large text string into variable length strings without breaking words and keeping linebreaks and spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815021/split-large-text-string-into-variable-length-strings-without-breaking-words-and)

Comment: What should be the output for the given example input?

Comment: In this case I should get: "THIS IS A" "LONG DESC 7" "X7 NEEDS" "SPLITTING"

Comment: Is that split in '7X7' a hard requirement? You could get an easier expression if you just split on word boundaries.

Comment: Why are you using a `dict` for the line lengths?  You could just use a list: `lineLengths = [ 9, 11, 12, 14, 14 ]`

Comment: @ThomasFenzl The regex split with the lookaround is necessary because I have much longer dimensions that need to be broken up in some way without a loss of information. An example might be `LONG DESC 4500X1600X3200 SOME TEXT HERE` which is still just about splittable but in an ugly manner

Comment: @MarkReed I just happened to implement it that way. If the list is significantly better for performance then that works but I mostly just hacked this together this morning

Comment: So you're splitting into words, but then splitting and recombining those words based on a maximum field size?  That seems odd.  Where does the 40 come from, when the lineLengths add up to 60?

Comment: It's not about performance, it's about using the right tool for the job.  Your code shows a marked lack of lists, which would be the more logical choice for not only your `lineLengths`, but also your `lineStr`s, `lineNumDict`, `lineOut`s...

Comment: @MarkReed Essentially, yes. It was the first thought that came to mind when I thought about working out how to split an inputted string across the line layout. The 40 characters is a system limitation while the line layout is a physical representation of the tag that the description will be split into (known as a Eurotag here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because you have the *for words in splitted* loop inside your loop with the lineLen condition. You have to do this:

```
    if len(inputStr) > 40:
        print "The short description is longer than 40 characters"
    else:
        for word in splitted:
            if lineNum > 5:
                 break
            if word != None:
                if len(lineNumDict[lineNum]+word) <= lineLengths[lineNum]:
                    lineNumDict[lineNum] += word
                else:
                    lineNum += 1
            else:
                if len(lineNumDict[lineNum])+1 <= lineLengths[lineNum]:
                    lineNumDict[lineNum] += " "
                else:
                    lineNum += 1
```

Also lineStr1, lineStr2 and so on won't be changed, you have to access the dict directly (strings are immutable). I tried it and got the results working:

```
    print("Lines: %s" % lineNumDict)
```

Gives:

```
    Lines: {1: 'THIS IS A', 2: 'LONG DESC 7', 3: '7 NEEDS ', 4: '', 5: ''}
```

Comment: This works nicely but it seems to drop both the "X" and the "SPLITTING". I've changed the `else` part of the nested `if` to then attempt to add the word to the line and if that single word is too long then to `print` that the word needs splitting and this seems to work perfectly. Thanks for the help

Comment: Yeah well the else case just dropped the word, so no wonder. I only looked at the loop, actually.

Answer (score 0):

```
for word in splitted:
    ...
    lineNum += 1
```

your code increments `lineNum` by the number of words in `splitted`, i.e. 16 times.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you properly but I only want it to increment a `lineNum` (and so move to the next line) if adding a word would take it over the `lineLength` limit. The `if` blocks should make that work unless I've missed something?

Comment: Yes, but your code has way to prevent ``lineNum`` from exceeding 5.

Comment: I'm still not following you. The lineNum should only increment if it was unable to fit the word on the line. Looking at it now though I don't think it would then add that word to the next line and instead skip to the next word. This needs changing too.

Comment: You are getting a ``keyError`` because in this line ``lineNumDict[lineNum]``, ``lineNum`` is 6, which is not a key in ``lineNumDict``.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if a properly commented regular expression wouldn't be easier to understand?

```
lineLengths = {1:9,2:11,3:12,4:14,5:14}
inputStr = "THIS IS A LONG DESC 7X7 NEEDS SPLITTING" 
import re
pat = """
(?:                     # non-capture around the line as we want to drop leading spaces
    \s*                 # drop leading spaces
    (.{{1,{max_len}}})  # up to max_len characters, will be added through 'format'
    (?=[\b\sX]|$)       # and using word breaks, X and string ending as terminators
                        # but without capturing as we need X to go into the next match
)?                      # and ignoring missing matches if not all lines are necessary
"""

# build a pattern matching up to 5 lines with the corresponding max lengths
pattern = ''.join(pat.format(max_len=x) for x in lineLengths.values())

re.match(pattern, inputStr, re.VERBOSE).groups()
#  Out: ('THIS IS A', 'LONG DESC 7', '7 NEEDS', 'SPLITTING', None)
```

Also, there is no real point in using a dict for line_lengths, a list would do nicely.